# save a map in ROS

Tags: ros, mapserver

I'm using ros indigo. When I am doing mapping then save it by:

```
map_server map_server -f 'location'
```

It gives me a warning that ...

```
Using deprecated map server interface. Please switch to a new interface.
```

and error that

```
map_server could not open -f
```

what can I do?

Comment: `-f` argument is for `map_saver` node, not in `map_server` node.

Answer (score 5):

map_saver, not map_server :)

`$ rosrun map_server map_saver -f 'file'`

Answer (score 1):

`map_server` from `map_server` package does not have `-f` argument.

I think you are mistaking it for `map_saver` which has `-f` argument.

you can check out it's wiki page here on [ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server)